# node.js: socket.on does not work

Tags: node.js

I have a problem. I'm making experiments with node.js, because later i want to program a 1:1-Chat.
I have a file send.html and a file receive.html. In the file send.html I emit to a node.js-Server with the following code:

```
 document.getElementById("buttonmessagesend").onclick = function()
 {
var text1="fester Text";
socket.emit('chatwunsch', {text: text1 });
    alert("Alarm");

 }
```

The node.js-Server recieves the event:

```
  socket.on("chatwunsch", function(data) {
  .....
```

He sends then on this event with

```
 socket.emit('chatwunschvon', { message: data.text});
```

This seems to work because the console of the node.js-Server shows:

```
 debug - websocket writing 5:::{"Name":"chatwunschvon","args":[{"message":"fester Text"}]}
```

And now, at the receive.html is the problem, because nothing is shown:

```
 socket.on('chatwunschvon', function(data){

  var message=data.message;
  localStorage.setItem('message', message);                 

  document.getElementById("chatfenster").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('message');   
  });

 </script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You sure it's not a localStorage problem? Maybe try just outputting the message from Socket?

```
document.getElementById("chatfenster").innerHTML = data.message;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where are you connecting to the socket backend. For example you could put something like

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my.websocket.com:3000');
socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    console.log('Connected to the websocket');
}
```

on both send.html and receive.html. That way you could tell, by looking at the console, if they are performing an initial handshake with socket.io.

Comment: thanks, but this is alright because on the Server console Comes the message "Client authorized for...." and a id-number.....for both files

Comment: What if you put the send and receive code in the same html file? There's a chance that the backend is answering to the original sender only, omitting the purported receiver. You could also try using *socket.join(roomname)* to make both ends join the same chatroom, and them *socket.broadcast.to(roomname).emit(...)* to address everyone in the chatroom.

Comment: thanks, that will be function. okay, i wan't to prog one Chatroom for every User and for every chatpartner a separate Button to Switch between all chatpartners..similar the Chat from lablue.de....i need hence anyway one(!) File 'chatbox.php'.